# How to display only unique messages when using flash in flask

Tags: python, flask

When using the `flash` functionality in flask, I have a couple of functions. I call f1, which calls f2 x times, which calls f3 y times. I get a inconsistency in f3, so I want to flash it in f3. However, I don't want to pass the inconsistency all the way down to f1 again, which results in the fact that the message in currently being flashed multiple times because the inconsistency occurs multiple times. Letting the user know 1 time is enough to determine the cause of it.

So I want to only display unique messages.

Minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'arstarst'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('banana', 'red')
    flash('apple', 'green')
    flash('banana', 'red')
    flash('pear', 'blue')
    return render_template_string('''
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for category, message in messages %}
            <p style="color: {{category}}">{{message}}</p>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    ''')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- Make an emtpy dict in jinja
- Loop over messages
- Check if the message is in the dict
- If not, add to the dict and print the message
- If so, do nothing

Example:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'arstarst'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('banana', 'red')
    flash('apple', 'green')
    flash('banana', 'red')
    flash('pear', 'blue')
    return render_template_string('''
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% set printed_messages = dict() %}
          {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% if message not in printed_messages %}
              <p style="color: {{category}}">{{message}}</p>
              {% set x = printed_messages.__setitem__(message, "value")  %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    ''')
```