# Flask flash message on all endpoints

Tags: python, flask

In my Flask app I have user management done via `flask.session`. So all info about logged in user is stored in `session`. When some new user registers, in database I create new row with one attribute being `verified` set to false and the same information is stored in `session['user']['verified']`. When user browses the website, no matter which endpoint, I want to `flash` him a message, that he still did not verify his email address.

So far I managed to do this by creating `@after_request` method like so:

```
@app.after_request
def check_user_verification_status(response):
    try:
        if not session['user']['verified']:
            flash("Your email address is still not verified, ...")
    except Exception:
        pass
    return response
```

This way the flash message really appears on all endpoints, but sometimes it appears duplicated because of some redirects being made. I solved the duplication problem following this answer:
[Flask - duplicates flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215349/how-to-display-only-unique-messages-when-using-flash-in-flask)

But when I am on main page and click on logout button, which redirects to endpoint `logout` (the endpoint logs out user - deletes user info from session - and redirects to main page), the flash message about not verified user also appears, even when no user is then technically logged in, because of finished original request, which was processed just before the redirect to logout endpoint and there was still user info in session.

Is there some solution to this problem. Something like "After request for all endpoints which will be called only once after all redirects" so it flashes the message just once (or zero times when the condition is not met)?

Comment: I hope you'll get a better answer, because I find the following idea more or less an ugly hack: Flash a special "control message" at logout and expand the flash message handling in Jinja2: first check all messages if the special logout message in present in flashed messages. If yes, don't display the "not verified" messages (and of course hide the control message too).

Comment: This could work and I will probably do it if no other solution appears. But as you said. it is kind of hacky and I also hope some other solution appears. Nevertheless thank you for your proposal and possible solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved current problem by editing of my `layout.html` page.

Every Jinja template in my app uses layout so the solution was to use simple Jinja if statement, which asked for `verified` variable. If it is true, it just shows `div` with message informing user, that email address is not verified. I added to the `div` the same class as classic flash messages have and this way it looks exactly the same as flash message.

```
{% if not verified %}
  <div class="msg info">Your email address is still not verified, ...</div>
{% endif %}
```

And the `verified` variable is always refreshed in `@before_request` method and set to `g.verified` (global variable - `flask.g`). This is then passed to every Jinja template (every endpoint) by overriding `render_template()` method as follows:

```
import flask
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def set_user_info():
    g.verified = is_user_verified()

def render_template(template, **kwargs):
    return flask.render_template(template, verified=g.config, **kwargs)
```

It may not be the best solution, but I like it a bit more than solution mentioned in comment below the question.